# show on a datagrid in red changed text in a datatable WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatable

How can I show in red text the value of a cell in a DataTable, when it is different from the same cell in another DataTable? In the final application the tables will be generated from changing csv files. So I have to replace autogenerated columns. I understood that you need a DataGridTemplateColumn for that, setting the CellTemplate to a resource. However this replaced column then is not part of the visual tree and therefore binding doesn't work.

The article [*How to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited*](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)  shows that a converter implementing the Freezable object should solve that. Trying to figure out this solution, I made next simplified example. But it displays the last value of the cell in all cells of the column where the change occurs, and all in red:

[image]

The ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        //private Model _Model; //for clarity left out
        private DataTable _propDataTable;
        public DataTable propDataTable
        {
            get { return _propDataTable; }
            set
            {
                _propDataTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("propDataTable");
            }
        }
        private DataTable propCopyDataTable;
        private string _sB;
        public string sB
        {
            get { return _sB; }
            set
            {
                _sB = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("sB");
            }
        }
        private bool _bB = false;
        public bool bB
        {
            get { return _bB; }
            set
            {
                _bB = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("bB");
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            propDataTable = new DataTable();

            propDataTable.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
            propDataTable.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
            DataRow row0 = propDataTable.NewRow();
            DataRow row1 = propDataTable.NewRow();
            row0[0] = "A0";
            row0[1] = "B0";
            row1[0] = "A1";
            row1[1] = "B1";
            propDataTable.Rows.Add(row0);
            propDataTable.Rows.Add(row1);

            propCopyDataTable = propDataTable.Copy();
            //now set a different value in propCopyDataTable
            propCopyDataTable.Rows[1][1] = "Changed";
            //find out which cells in column B are different
            //try to show in red text which cell changed
            for (int i = 0; i < propDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = propDataTable.Rows[i];
                DataRow drc = propCopyDataTable.Rows[i];
                sB = (string) dr["B"];
                if (dr["B"].ToString().Equals(drc["B"].ToString()))
                {
                    bB = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bB = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ObjectToForegroundConverter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
    public class ObjectToForegroundConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush b = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            try
            {
                bool changedValue = (bool)value;
                if (changedValue)
                {
                    b = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error: {0}", e));//instance not set to a etc.
            }

            return b;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The BindingProxy converter:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {  
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }
        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

The XAML control:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <myViewModel:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <myViewModel:ObjectToForegroundConverter x:Key="MyObjectToForegroundConverter"/>
        <myViewModel:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="changedBColumn" >
            <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Data.sB,Source={StaticResource proxy},Mode=OneWay}" 
            Foreground="{Binding Data.bB,Converter={StaticResource MyObjectToForegroundConverter},Source={StaticResource proxy},Mode=OneWay}"
            />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myXAMLtable" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding propDataTable}">            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
            {
                case "B":
                    {
                        DataGridTemplateColumn BTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                        BTemplateColumn.Header = "B";
                        BTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["changedBColumn"];
                        e.Column = BTemplateColumn;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is each cell need a bool to indicate the state of changing. But you have just 1 property for a column in your view-model. That means all the cells in the same column will have the same state depending on that property. That explains why all the cells in the column `B` are red because the property `bB` is set to true and bound to all cells in the column `B`.

You need an item class (instead of just simple string value) to hold the state, something like this:

```
public class Item {
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public Item(string value){
        Value = value;
    }
    public bool IsChanged { get; private set;}
    public void SetChanged(){
       IsChanged = true;
    }
    public override string ToString(){
       return Value;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other){
        var item = other as Item;
        if(item == null) return false;
        return item.Value == Value;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(){
        if(Value == null) return base.GetHashCode();
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now your `DataTable` should be created like this:

```
propDataTable = new DataTable();

propDataTable.Columns.Add("A", typeof(Item));
propDataTable.Columns.Add("B", typeof(Item));
DataRow row0 = propDataTable.NewRow();
DataRow row1 = propDataTable.NewRow();
row0[0] = new Item("A0");
row0[1] = new Item("B0");
row1[0] = new Item("A1");
row1[1] = new Item("B1");
propDataTable.Rows.Add(row0);
propDataTable.Rows.Add(row1);

propCopyDataTable = propDataTable.Copy();
//now set a different value in propCopyDataTable
propCopyDataTable.Rows[1][1] = new Item("Changed");
//find out which cells in column B are different
//try to show in red text which cell changed
for (int i = 0; i < propDataTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
     DataRow dr = propDataTable.Rows[i];
     DataRow drc = propCopyDataTable.Rows[i];
     if (!object.Equals(dr["B"], drc["B"])) {
         (dr["B"] as Item).SetChanged();
     }         
}
```

Now you also need to modify your converter like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    SolidColorBrush b = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);            
    var item = (Item)value;
    if (item.IsChanged) {
        b = Brushes.Red;
    }        
    return b;
}
```

The XAML should also be modified like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="changedBColumn" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [B], Mode=OneWay}" 
        Foreground="{Binding [B],Converter={StaticResource MyObjectToForegroundConverter}, 
                     Mode=OneWay}"
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

NOTE: You don't need to use a proxy ***unless*** you want to bind the controls in DataTemplate to the main view-model. But actually that's wrong. What actually you need to bind your controls to here is each data row. In each cell template, the implicit `DataContext` is actually a `DataRowView`. So you don't need to set the Source explicitly. Just bind it normally. In the above XAML, I use the Path `[B]` meaning the indexer `[]` with a string key `B` is passed in directly - it is equivalent to the call `someDataRowView["B"]`. Also the Converter has the passed-in value as an `Item` (not a bool). Every time changing a value for a cell, you need to set it to a new `Item`, don't simply change the `Item.Value` property because it does not support `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Although in this case looks like you simply want to test it.

If you want to test the proxy technique, try creating another example. In fact that technique ***does*** work in your original code, when it successfully binds all cells to the `bB` property of your main view-model which is passed in via the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensible explanation. it works great!